# How can I use a class before defining it?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

```
class Node
{
    string name;
    Node previous;
};
```

```
 Error: Node::previous uses "Node" which is being defined.
```

How can I get this to work in C++? It works in C#.

**EDIT:**

Why `Node* previous` works?

Comment: I used pointer as suggested by everyone. It works! But why?

Comment: The size of the pointer is known. Because you are declaring Node by value the compiler needs to know how much space to reserve. But the class is still being defined so this is not possible.

Comment: In C# a variable of type Node is not the node object but a *reference* to such a node object. This implicit indirection doesn't exist in C++. If you want indirection in C++ you have to explicitly use a pointer. This is an important difference and you have to understand this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use pointers. `Node* previous;` would solve the problem.

As you're doing it now, you actually try to make your class infinitely large.

Answer (score 8):

Use a pointer or a reference.

For example:

```
Node* previous;
```

The only restriction is that a class cannot have an actual field of itself, likely for construction reason. Think about it, if every Box contains another Box inside it, how would you end up with a finite number of boxes?

If I'm not mistaken, C# only uses references for class types (as does Java), so you're using a reference there, just not seeing it.

Answer (score 5):

For the edit, think about it, your `node` contains another `node` into it which contains another one inside. So you have an infinite sequence of nodes contained in one another. What you want is a pointer to the location where the next `node` is stored. So you should change it to `Node*`.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, declaring `previous` like that gives you a reference. In C++, declaring `previous` like that gives you an object, embedded in each object of class `Node`.

An object can't have an object *of the same class* embedded in it, recursively. `previous.name` would have to exist (and have storage allocated to it), as would `previous.previous.name`, and so on infinitely, all in a single memory allocation. The size of a `Node` object would have to be at least as much as the size of a `string` object plus the size of a `Node` object (which is impossible since `string` is more than 0 bytes). And other such contradictions.

As others say, use a pointer: `Node *previous` or a reference `Node &previous`. Or a `std::deque<std::string>` ;-)

You might like to know that C++ differs from C# in other ways which will spoil your day if you're trying to write a singly-linked list by porting C# code. No garbage collection, for example. You can't write correct C++ code without understanding the C++ object model.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am re-learning C++,haven't used since long time :)

Answer (score 2):

Think about a Car object "in the real world".  It can contain a reference to another Car object via the VIN number.  It could even contain a reference to itself, or to the VIN value of 0 (NULL, or NO CAR).

But what if you literally wanted another Car OBJECT inside every Car Object?  How would that work?  What Car object would the containing Car object contain?

Java and C# don't actually place THE OBJECT inside the containing class, but a REFERENCE to the object.  Languages like C++ allow you to specify whether there is an OBJECT contained within the class, a REFERENCE to another OBJECT contained within the class, or even a POINTER to another OBJECT contained within the class:

```
class Car
{
   Engine engine;  // Car CONTAINS an Engine object
};

class Car
{
   Engine &engine;  // Car contains a REFERENCE to an Engine object
};

class Car
{
  Engine *pEngine;  // Car contains a POINTER to an Engine object
};
```

Eventually you'll get to the point where you know when and why to use the first, the second, or the third, but that's a different question altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't Node be a pointer?